# Stop after First statement in an IF

Tags: python

I have a problem in my IF, I would like to check one of the two statements. When list2 is not None no problem. But, when list2 is None, IF does check list2.val which raise an error even if "not list2" is True.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next

class Solution(object):
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1, list2):
        """
        :type list1: Optional[ListNode]
        :type list2: Optional[ListNode]
        :rtype: Optional[ListNode]
        """
        res = ListNode(0)
        curr = res

        while list1 or list2:
            if not list2 or list1.val <= list2.val:
                curr.next = ListNode(list1.val)
                list1 = list1.next if list1 else None
            elif not list1 or list2.val < list1.val:
                curr.next = ListNode(list2.val)
                list2 = list2.next if list2 else None
            curr = curr.next if curr else None
        return res.next
```

Error :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'
    if not list2 or list1.val <= list2.val:
Line 17 in mergeTwoLists (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().mergeTwoLists(param_1, param_2)
Line 48 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 58 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen. `or` is short-circuiting, so it doesn't evaluate the second argument when the first expression is true.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with `list2`, rather than `list1`? You'll get that error if `list1` is `None`.

Comment: I think Barmar is right, it is probably a problem when `list1` is None